# How to pass additional arguments when updating a matplotlib widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, lambda, matplotlib-widget

I have multiple similar `Slider`s, and want to call the function `update` with a certain argument when a the corresponding slider is changed. Passing additional parameters should work similarly to other widgets, e.g., `on_clicked()` of `Button`.

Simplified example using [base code from Slider demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html):

```
def update(val, string):
    line.set_ydata(f(t, amp_slider.val, freq_slider.val))
    print(string)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

freq_slider.on_changed(update("Frequency updated"))
amp_slider.on_changed(update("Amplitude updated"))
```

The following doesn't pass the updated `val` at all, and hence obviously doesn't work. According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html) on_changed only accepts a callable function as a parameter. Is there a way to solve this without somehow incorporating `mpl_connect`, e.g. using a `lambda` function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` to call `update` with additional parameters. Note that `new_val` is actually the current value of the slider here.

```
freq_slider.on_changed(lambda new_val: update(new_val, "Frequency updated"))
```

Below is an example using modified code from before

```
def update(val, string="Updated without additional string param"):
    line.set_ydata(f(t, amp_slider.val, freq_slider.val))
    print(string)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


freq_slider.on_changed(lambda new_val: update(new_val, "Frequency updated"))
amp_slider.on_changed(update)  # no string arg
```